# Symony 3.0 BootStrap.php.cache issue - missing file

Tags: symfony

i am running 16.04 ubuntu with Symfony 3.0
This is the error in aApache logs  i am getting and i dont know how to fix it. Can you please help?

```
PHP Warning: include_once(/home/tl/tl/apps/api/Symfony/3.0/web/../var/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/webcampak/webcampak/apps/api/Symfony/3.0/web/app.php on line 9, referer:
```

Comment: Can you check if the file is really missing? If not, it could be a permission issue, use `chmod` or `chown` to fix those. If the file is not there, try running `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` (or `app/console cache:clear --env=prod` if you use the older directory structure). You can skip `--env=prod` when it is not a production server

Comment: Thank you for your reply and recommendation. I have checked inside /var/ and bootsrap is not inside. I have run command and restarted apache. Throwing same fault

Comment: As far as I can tell the bootstrap cache should be created with `composer install`, but it will only be loaded when you use an older PHP version (5.x). So, I guess you could try running composer again or you could update PHP using the alternative packages from `ppa:ondrej/php`